# Database structure for categories, sub-categories, and services

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.5 and MySql. I cannot figure out how to relate Categories, and Sub Categories to Services without adding a `subCategoryID` column to the `Services` table.

Currently this is my table structure

Service_Categories

```
id, name
1, Legal Services
2, Personal Drivers
```

Service_Sub_Categories

```
id, ServiceCategoryID, name
1, 1, US Legal Services
2, 1, Europe Legal Services
3, 1, Canada Legal Services
```

Services

```
id, serviceCategoryID, name
1, 1, US Legal Services Comapny INC
2, 1, Canada Legal Services Company INC
3, 2, JSY Personal Drivers
4, 2, XYZ Personal Drivers
```

One service must have at least 1 Service Category but it can also have 0 or more Sub-Categories

As you can see, Personal Drivers has no sub-category, but Legal Services has many Sub-Categories. When a user selects "US Legal Services" I only want to pull those up. I could easily add a `subCategoryID` column to the `Services` table but in the future I may have sub-sub-categories. What is the best way to structure my tables?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get all the subcategories of the service, you can use the following relationships:

Service Model

```
public function category() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Categories', 'id', 'service_category_id');
}
```

Categories Model

```
public function subCategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\subCategories', 'service_category_id');
}
```

Get all sub-categories for service id 1:

```
Service::find(1)->category->subCategories
```

---

Or if you need from the Category to get the Service and his all sub categories:

Categories Model

```
public function service() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Service', 'service_category_id');
}
```

Service Model

```
public function subCategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\subCategories', 'service_category_id');
}
```

And get all sub-categories for category id 1:

```
Categories::find(1)->service->subCategories;
```

**UPDATE**

Also you can use relation - Has Many Through

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through